# Read original markup in AngularJS before replacing with template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a fancy slider that allows the user to select a value in a range, and I'm trying to build it as an AngularJS directive. Each step in the range has a brief text description that is displayed at that position. For example:

```
 Temperature
                  Warm
[------------------^------]
 |     |     |     |     |
 Cold                  Hot
```

I would like to use this initial markup on the page, since it's semantic and degrades gracefully:

```
<div class="prompt scale">
    <label for="mySelect">Temperature</label>
    <select name="mySelect">
        <option value="1">Cold</option>
        <option value="2">Cool</option>
        <option value="3">Neutral</option>
        <option value="4">Warm</option>
        <option value="5">Hot</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I would then completely replace this with the fancy slider's markup. However, doing this would require that Angular be able to read the original markup in order to extract the data (the values and labels for each option) that it needs to render the fancy slider. However, I can't find any place where I can get a reference to the original element and its children. When declaring the directive, the compile() and link() functions both reference the template element, not the original. How can I read the original markup, including getting access to its descendants?

Comment: I don't get it: why would Angular have to extract the data from the markup?

Comment: Because the original markup contains the options (1=Cold, 2=Cool, ...), and that markup is going to be replaced with completely different markup. I think I may have discovered the answer to my own question; still looking at it.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier if the directive were provided with the options by using the scope? Something like this: `<fancy-slider options="myOptions"></fancy-slider>`

Comment: But he's also looking for graceful degradation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use the template property on the directive config object I guess you lose the ability to see the original.

I think to do what you're doing effectively you need to use the compile directive function which I'm not well-versed in.  I got away without it using it to show you this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2TPWA/

Basically create directives for each of the significant pieces of data.  Have them share a controller to register all this data.  By doing it this way the parent directive can have its children not necessarily be a specified depth from it.  Hide (or remove if you prefer) the original markup and then create your widget based on the consolidated information.

In your case I'd make directives for wiring everything up like you've seen here and another directive which would be the widget, by itself, that could be created with maybe attributes or a config object like another answerer suggested.

```
<div>
<div sliding-scale class="prompt scale">
<label sliding-scale-title for="mySelect">Temperature</label>
<select name="mySelect">
    <option sliding-scale-option value="1">Cold</option>
    <option sliding-scale-option value="2">Cool</option>
    <option sliding-scale-option value="3">Neutral</option>
    <option sliding-scale-option value="4">Warm</option>
    <option sliding-scale-option value="5">Hot</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('slidingScaleTitle', function () {
    return {
        require: '^slidingScale',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.setTitle(element.text());
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('slidingScaleOption', function () {
    return {
        require: '^slidingScale',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.addOption({ 
                value: attrs.value,
                text: element.text()
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('slidingScale', function ($compile) {
    var template = '<div><b>{{ title }}</b><ul><li ng-repeat="o in options"><b>{{ o.value }}:</b> {{ o.text }} </li></ul>';

    return {
        // You should make this its own controller if you want this unit-tested.
        // I'm inlining it as an example.
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var title;
            var options = [];

            this.setTitle = function (value) {
                title = value;
            };
            this.getTitle = function () {
                return title;
            };
            this.getOptions = function () {
                return options;
            }
            this.addOption = function (value) {
                options.push(value);
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            scope.$watch(controller.getTitle, function (value) {
                scope.title = value;
            });

            scope.$watch(controller.getOptions, function (value) {
                scope.options = value;
            });

            element.children().css('display', 'none');
            fancySliderElement = angular.element(template);
            element.append(fancySliderElement);
            $compile(fancySliderElement)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the template/templateUrl property is to blame. Your fix seems like it would work, but there's another solution that I'm testing out now that might be even better. If that doesn't work, I'll try out yours.